# C# Windows Form display Facebook comments

Tags: c#, winforms, facebook-comments

i would like to add [facebook plugin - comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) into my c# application. (Not apply at asp.net)
However, I am not able to put the generated HTML5 coding into the webBrowser in my program.

```
string fb_comments = "<html><body><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>....</script><form id=\"form1\" runat=\"server\"><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"https://www.facebook.com\" data-width=\"446\" data-num-posts=\"2\"></div></form></body></html>";
DisplayHtml(fb_comments);
```

Could you suggest any ways for me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you really don't want to use a `WebBrowser` to integrate with Facebook. They have an API that can be used. [Here is a tutorial](http://codesamplez.com/programming/facebook-api-access-token-using-c-sharp) that will get you started getting connected to the API, then just leverage the API to get what you want.

The spectrum of what you need is a bit broad because there is a lot more information that would be necessary, like API keys, and exactly what you're trying to access. But that will get you started.